# Get related videos with Youtube API on Android

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I need to get related videos with Youtube API on Android. Is it possible to configure YoutubePlayer to implement this functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the response and use the URL to get related videos

> The related videos feed contains a list of videos that are related to
>   another video. YouTube algorithmically selects the set of related
>   videos.
>
> Each video entry in an API response contains a series of  tags.
>   The  tag that has a rel attribute value of
>   http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/#video.related identifies the
>   URL for retrieving other videos related to that video entry. (The
>    tag's href attribute identifies the URL.)

```
<link rel="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.related"
     type="application/atom+xml"
     href="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ZTUVgYoeN_b/related?v=2"/>
```

From https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#Related_videos_feed

Comment: Oh, thanks! I missed this topic in docs

Comment: Np. Please accept as answer if it solves your problem.